# Unable to perform scatter execution in python

Tags: python, dictionary, mpi

I am planning to use MPI scatter and gather for one of my requirement.

I have to include MPI scatter and gather in python to parse a json file and then scatter the data and use that to to filter out the required properties.

I have no issues in parsing the json.

```
if rank == 0 :
   for x in newData1:
        for j in range(size):
            result[j].append(x)
    data = result
    print(data)
else:
    data = None

chunks = comm.scatter(chunks, root=0)
```

newData is a list of dictionaries in python.

```
 cntr = fuction_name(chunks)
```

is the function call to manipulate the scattered data.

when I tried to print the scattered data I am getting below output:

```
rank 0 
chunks 0
rank 1 
chunks 1
```

Below is the error I get when I try to run my program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpi.py", line 192, in <module>
    cntr = function_name(chunks)
  File "mpi.py", line 60, in make_grid_list
    for i in range(len(data)):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpi.py", line 192, in <module>
    cntr = function_name(chunks)
  File "mpi.py", line 60, in make_grid_list
    for i in range(len(data)):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: it seems `data` is an `int`, but you want it to be a `list`.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf the scatter data should print the data result and not the integers right? I tried to print the chunks and the chunks are alright but when try to scatter the chunks and then print the scattered result I am getting below result 
"rank 0
chunks 0

rank 2
chunks 2

rank 3
chunks 3

rank 1
chunks 1
"

Do you have any idea why is this happening?